# Looking for an element using xpath in chrome console initially returns nothing, after clicking inspect and searching again, it works

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

After a page loads, I'm searching for an element on the chrome console using this string:

`$x("//img[@title='Support Center']")`

It returns [], meaning no such element was found.
After that, I right-click the element, click inspect, then go back to the console and search again.

At that second search I do get a response with [img], which is the element I was looking for. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

With HTML, there is no title attributes for images, maybe you're looking for the alt attribute ?

(source : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

---

For me, on Google Chrome 60.0.3112.78, it works even right after page load (tested for alt tag). Are you using the last version of Google Chrome ? Have you tried with another version ?